# Nodejs Sharp how to extend image to the right multiples times?

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, sharp

I am attempting to create an image of a credit score color scale bar, but I am experiencing an issue where the last colour overlaps with the others.

```
const sharp = require("sharp");

function generateCreditScoreColorScaleBar(width, height, minScore, maxScore) {
  const image = sharp({
    create: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      channels: 3,
      background: "white",
    },
  });

  const colorWidth = width / (maxScore - minScore + 1);

  for (let score = minScore; score <= maxScore; score++) {
    const x = (score - minScore) * colorWidth;
    const color = getColorForScore(score);
    console.log(
      `Score: ${score}, x: ${x}, width: ${colorWidth}, color: ${color}`
    );
    image
      .extend({
        top: 0,
        left: Math.ceil(x),
        bottom: 0,
        right: Math.ceil(width - (x + colorWidth)),
        background: color,
      })
      .composite([
        {
          input: "layer3.png",
          blend: "multiply",
        },
      ]);
  }

  return image;
}

function getColorForScore(score) {
  // Define your color mapping based on credit score ranges
  if (score >= 800) {
    return "#00FF00"; // Green for excellent scores
  } else if (score >= 700) {
    return "#FFFF00"; // Yellow for good scores
  } else if (score >= 600) {
    return "#FFA500"; // Orange for fair scores
  } else {
    return "#FF0000"; // Red for poor scores
  }
}

// Usage example
const width = 400;
const height = 50;
const minScore = 300;
const maxScore = 500;

generateCreditScoreColorScaleBar(width, height, minScore, maxScore)
  .toFile("credit_score_scale_bar.png")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Credit score color scale bar image generated successfully.");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(
      "Error generating credit score color scale bar image:",
      error
    );
  });
```

This is the image result:
[image]

Comment: please show what you see

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I add the image result to the question. TY in advance